# python's module gives zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file for zip files

Tags: python, exception, zip

```
import zipfile

for i in range(1,2000):
    try:
        filezip = zipfile.ZipFile(r'C:\Users\gil\Desktop\New folder\archives\unzipme.'+str(i))

        infolist = filezip.comment
        print (infolist)
    except:
        print(i)
```

some files throwes exception - zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file 
but all of them are zip files

Comment: Does this happen with all zip files? Can you provide a sample file?

Comment: no ,only some of them. how can i upload the file?

Comment: Are they all produced in the same way? Is it possible that some of them really aren't zip files? If no, how have you verified that?

Comment: yes the same way,different computers gave error on different files so i think they all zip,how can i upload a smple? @L3viathan